# Set "Automatically link new work in this build" at queue time in VSTS build

Tags: azure-pipelines

I need the ability to set "Automatically link new work in this build" option at queue time. Is there a "secret" variable (like System.Debug or Build.Clean) that I can use?

Comment: Not clear it, do you mean link a new work item to this build? Can you provide the sample to explain it.

Comment: When I queue a build, I want the ability to override "Automatically link new work in this build" option.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such feature in VSTS now, I submit a user voice here:[Allow override some setting of build definition when queue build](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34508560-allow-override-some-setting-of-build-definition-wh) that you can vote and follow.