# VSTS build "magic" variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

A question related to [Set "Automatically link new work in this build" at queue time in VSTS build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751186/set-automatically-link-new-work-in-this-build-at-queue-time-in-vsts-build). Is there a documented list of VSTS build "magic" variables (like Build.Clean, Build.SyncSources, System.Debug) etc.?

Comment: If the variables are not documented, we recommend you do not take a dependency on them.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Predefined variables of Build:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch

Comment: This link does not say anything about Build.Clean or Build.SyncSources.

Comment: Where did you find these variables?

Comment: I found the Build.SynSources one here. The answer was posted by @PatrickLu-MSFT. I wonder where he found it?

Comment: Can you provide the link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421482/is-it-able-to-ignore-disable-the-first-step-get-source-in-vnext-build/46422981#46422981

Comment: Actually, he mentions this blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2017/09/25/disabling-get-sources-step-in-vnext-build/

Comment: There is no documentation lists `Build.SyncSources` variable, so there is a separate blog to introduce it. I have submitted a feedback on [this website](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/1039) to ask adding this variable on the [Predefined variables of Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch).

Comment: Build.SyncSources is just one of the variables. There is also Agent.Diagnostic. What I believe we need is a documentation for all of these variables.

Comment: Please click `content feedback` on this website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#qa